# how do you make scrollbar work in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am creating a highchart where I would like the scrollbar to be enabled. My scroll bar is not working, any ideas what I might be missing here?

```
$('#add_trans').highcharts('StockChart', {
            chart: {
                borderColor: '#801500',
                borderRadius: 20,
                borderWidth: 1,
                type: 'line',
                events: {
                    load: function(chart) {
                        this.setTitle(null, {

                        });
                    }
                },
                zoomType: 'x'

            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: true
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true
                },
            rangeSelector: {
                buttons: [{
                        type: 'minute',
                        count: 60,
                        text: 'hourly'
                    }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }],
               // selected: 1
            },
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: true
            },
            navigator : {
                enabled : true
            },
             xAxis: {
             labels: {
                enabled: true
                }

            },

            yAxis : {
                title : {
                    text : 'Response Time'
                },

                tickInterval: 100
            },

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some mistakes possible for error:

- There is no `series:{}` in your highcharts code, so no data for your chart is in the code.
- extra commas causes the issues so remove the:

code:

```
yAxis : {
title : {
    text : 'Response Time'
},
 tickInterval: 100
},//comma from here if there is no section after it
```

and:

```
rangeSelector: {
    buttons: [{
            type: 'minute',
            count: 60,
            text: 'hourly'
        }, {
        type: 'all',
        text: 'All'
    }],         //from here if next statement is commented
   // selected: 1
},
```

If your code still doesn't work, you could try changing this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
```

with this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.highcharts.com/js/highstock.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am already using highstock.js and I have removed the extra commas. No change, I still cannot scroll.

Comment: I am using jquery tabs and for some reason it is impacting highcharts, not sure what is going on